# Add foreign key to large data type like varchar(2000) mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table 'affiliate_stats' and 'transaction',
'affiliate_stats' have column 'affiliate_sales' varchar(2000) (child table),
and 'transaction' have column '_id' varchar(100) primary key (parent table)

when I add foerign key to 'affiliate_sales' referenced to '_id'
by
`ALTER TABLE` affiliate_stats `ADD CONSTRAINT`fk_affili_sales  `FOREIGN KEY (affiliate_sales)  REFERENCES transaction(`_id`);`

get me this error `Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes`
I know should two column size be equail, but in my case i need size different how to handle this problem also.
Searched in many sources and there is no clear answer and none of the solutions work for me.

Comment: if affiliate_sales is going to have a FK relationship with tranaction._id why aren't they the same size?

Comment: Why does `affiliate_sales` have a different length than `_id`? There's something you are not telling us clearly.

Comment: i'm edit my question, can you help me

Comment: Consider using an auto-incremented integer primary key. It is faster, simpler, uses less storage, and does not change; the number has no special meaning; no business decision will change it. If `_id` has business meaning, rename it to something else.

Comment: What is the [character set](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-character-set/) of the table and `varchar(2000)` column?

Comment: Normalize your database at least to 3NF, or use a NoSQL database for a NoSQL database design.

Comment: charcter set is ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

Comment: what is 3NF ...? get me a reference

Comment: 3NF is Third Normal Form. It's a database term-of-art. Normal Forms help you design tables that are easier to work with. You can [learn about database normalization here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-rdbms-concepts.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 byte`

`varchar(2000)` stores 2000 *characters*, but each character is not necessarily 1 byte. Simple European characters like a, 1, and ? are all one byte. However, ü or å or اَلْعَرَبِيَّةُ‎ take up multiple bytes.

---

> I know should two column size be equail, but in my case i need size different how to handle this problem also.

This is possible, [string types do not need to be of the same length](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

However, it is unnecessary. *It is impossible to have a key larger than 100 characters*. Your primary key is `varchar(100)`, so no foreign key will ever be larger than 100 characters.

However, [you seem to want to store two different types of data in this column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75725742/add-foreign-key-to-large-data-type-like-varchar2000-mysql-table/75725936#comment133587719_75725810). One is some sort of array type, and one is a foreign key. You can't. A [foreign key](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_foreignkey.asp) ensures that *every* value has a matching primary key value.

---

Instead, use an [auto-incrementing primary key](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_primarykey.asp) to link your tables together. It's simpler, faster, uses less storage, unambiguous, and never changes.

Add a new column as primary key to both tables. Then reference that.

---

You can't store multiple keys in one column. MySQL needs to be able to confirm that each foreign key has a matching primary key, and it can only do that by checking if they're exactly equal.

Instead, if each affilate_stats row is for multiple affiliate_sales, you need a [join table](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). This is called a 1-to-many relationship. One affiliate_stats row relates to many affiliate_sales.

```
-- I'm assuming we've changed to bigint primary keys.
create table affiliate_stats_sales (
    affiliate_sales_id bigint not null,
    foreign key(affiliate_sales_id) references affiliate_sales(id),

    affiliate_stats_id bigint not null,
    foreign key(affiliate_stats_id) references affiliate_stats(id)
);
```

Now for every affiliate_sale that you want to add to a row of affiliate_stats, insert a row into affiliate_stats_sales.

```
-- Relate affiliate_sale 100 to affiliate_stats 20
insert into affiliate_stats_sales(affiliate_sales_id, affiliate_stats_id) values (100, 20)
```

Sales and stats are related by joining with that table. For example, if you want to see the stats for sale 100.

```
select affiliate_stats.*
from affiliate_stats
join affiliate_stats_sales
  on affiliate_stats_sales.affiliate_stats_id = affiliate_stats.id
where affiliate_sales.id = 100
```

It's a bit difficult at first, but very powerful. That's how relational databases work.

Comment: "You can't store multiple keys in one column" - but MySQL can have a multi-column FK and FK.

Comment: @RickJames Are multi-column foreign keys relevant here?

Answer (score 2):

Alter your column `affiliate_sales` to be `VARCHAR(100)`.

```
ALTER TABLE `affiliate_stats` 
  MODIFY COLUMN affiliate_tales VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_affili_sales` 
  FOREIGN KEY (affiliate_sales) 
  REFERENCES transaction(`_id`);
```

If it's a foreign key to `transaction(_id)`, then it doesn't need to be `VARCHAR(2000)` because it could never hold a string longer than 100 characters anyway.

Before you do this, make sure there are no strings currently in that column longer than 100 characters.

---

Re your comment:

If you intend to store an "array" (i.e. a string with a comma-separated list) in the column, you should understand that you can't make a foreign key on it anyway. A foreign key requires that the column relate *one* value to a row in the `transaction` table. You can only store one id in the column if you add a foreign key constraint to it.

It sounds like you really have a many-to-many relationship between `affiliate_stats` and `transaction`. You need a third table to model a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: in affiliate_sales column, varchar(2000) because the data insert into column like array, And since there is no array in mysql I should declare varchar like you see varchr(2000),

Comment: @abdelrhman_sasalh That's what I was fearing. You need to fix your design to a relational design. In this case you are thinking in "NoSQL mode", that will degrade the performance of a relational database.

Comment: @abdelrhman_sasalh 1) If you declare `affiliate_stats._id` to be a foreign key of `affilidate_sales._id` it can only ever contain values which are already in `affilidate_sales._id`. 2) "Arrays" should be stored in [1-to-many join tables](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) or perhaps [as JSON](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-json/).

Comment: sir @TheImpaler, I want insert many record in one column, in this case I convert object to string for carries the records in relational database, in affiliate_sales column I have many records exceed varchar(100), how to handle this in relational database.

Comment: @The soution seems to be to add a foreign key in `transaction` that points to `affiliate_stats`. In your case, you are trying to place it in the wrong table.